# Cannot get the return value of implemented callable class always get TimeOutException

Tags: java, swing

I want to implement connection checker but the problem is I can't get the value of callable class, I already tried thread but I don't know how to return the value. Sorry I'm not familiar with Executor

Connection Checker Class

```
    public class ConnectionChecker implements Callable<Boolean> {

        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            try {
                String cmd = "";
                if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) {
                    // For Windows
                    cmd = "ping -n 1 " + "1.1.1.1";
                } else {
                    // For Linux and OSX
                    cmd = "ping -c 1 " + "https//www.apple.com";
                }
                Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                myProcess.waitFor();
                if (myProcess.exitValue() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("false");
                    return false;

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;

            }

        }
```

Main Method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Updater updater = new Updater(GUI.netStatusL, executor);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(updater, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GUI().frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
```

Updater Class

```
public class Updater implements Runnable {
    private final JLabel label;
    private final ExecutorService executor;


    public Updater(JLabel label, ExecutorService executor) {
        this.label = label;
        this.executor = executor;

    }

    public void run() {
        boolean connected = false;
        Callable<Boolean> callable = new ConnectionChecker();
        Future<Boolean> connHandle = executor.submit(callable);
        try {
            connHandle.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            connected = true;

        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            /* connected = false; */
            connected = false;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            /* Let it be handled higher elsewhere */
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } catch (CancellationException ex) {
            /* happens only if you actively cancel the Future */
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            /* connected = false */
        }

        final boolean result = connected;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (result)
                    label.setText("online");
                else
                    label.setText("offline");
            }
        });
```

I'm trying to use an Executor to implement a connection checker, but I'm having difficulty getting the return value from the callable class.

I faced error in this area throwing TimeoutException

```
<!-- -->
   try {
            connHandle.get(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            connected = true;

        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            /* connected = false; */
            connected = false;
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, modified, works for me:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class ConnectionChecker implements Callable<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        List<String> cmdList;
        try {
            // String cmd = "";
            if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) {
                // For Windows
                cmdList = List.of("ping", "-n", "1", "1.1.1.1");
                // cmd = "ping -n 1 " + "1.1.1.1";
            } else {
                // For Linux and OSX
                cmdList = List.of("ping", "-n", "1", "1.1.1.1");
                // cmd = "ping -c 1 " + "https//www.apple.com";
            }
            Process myProcess = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList).start();
            myProcess.waitFor();
            if (myProcess.exitValue() == 0) {
                System.out.println("true");
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("false");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ConnectionChecker checker = new ConnectionChecker();
            ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            Future<Boolean> future = service.submit(checker);
            service.shutdown();
            System.out.println("after shutdown");
            Boolean result = future.get();
            System.out.println("result: " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Note that it is better to use ProcessBuilder than Runtime().getRuntime()

and the GUI

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Gui extends JPanel {
    private static final int MIN_WIDTH = 500;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("................");
    private JButton button = new JButton("Start Action");
    
    public Gui() {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 2, 2));
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Value: "));
        topPanel.add(label);
        
        JPanel midPanel = new JPanel();
        midPanel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(e -> buttonAction());
        
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        add(topPanel);
        add(midPanel);
    }
    
    public JLabel getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    
    private void buttonAction() {
        ConnectionChecker checker = new ConnectionChecker();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        final Future<Boolean> future = service.submit(checker);
        service.shutdown();

        SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
                return future.get();
            }
            
            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    boolean result = get();
                    label.setText("" + result);
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    label.setText("failed");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
        int w = Math.max(superSz.width, MIN_WIDTH);
        int h = superSz.height;
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Gui mainPanel = new Gui();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        });
    }
}
```

This uses a SwingWorker to run the background code. I also call `shutdown()` on my service.

Although, if this were my code, I'd do something like:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class SwingConnectionChecker extends SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> {
    
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
        List<String> cmdList;
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) {
            // For Windows
            cmdList = List.of("ping", "-n", "1", "1.1.1.1");
            // cmd = "ping -n 1 " + "1.1.1.1";
        } else {
            // For Linux and OSX
            cmdList = List.of("ping", "-n", "1", "1.1.1.1");
        }
        Process myProcess = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList).start();
        myProcess.waitFor();
        if (myProcess.exitValue() == 0) {
            System.out.println("true");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
            return false;
        }
    }    
}
```

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Gui extends JPanel {
    private static final int MIN_WIDTH = 500;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("................");
    private JButton button = new JButton("Start Action");
    
    public Gui() {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 2, 2));
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Value: "));
        topPanel.add(label);
        
        JPanel midPanel = new JPanel();
        midPanel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(e -> buttonAction());
        
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        add(topPanel);
        add(midPanel);
    }
    
    public JLabel getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    
    private void buttonAction() {
        SwingConnectionChecker checkerWorker = new SwingConnectionChecker();
        checkerWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(pce -> {
            if (pce.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                try {
                    boolean result = checkerWorker.get();
                    label.setText("" + result);
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        checkerWorker.execute();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
        int w = Math.max(superSz.width, MIN_WIDTH);
        int h = superSz.height;
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Gui mainPanel = new Gui();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add updater class sir because I want to check my connection time to time by the way thank you very much for your effort... Appreciated!